# Is “get cut” a passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice, auxiliary-verbs, active-vs-passive

> The wild flowers and herbs ***get cut*** before they have a chance to flower
>   and propagate.

I think the sentence is in the passive voice. Why does the writer use ***get*** instead of ***are*** ? When we have to use get not verb to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is a passive construction.  "They get cut" can be phrased in the active voice: "Something cuts them".

Yes, there is a difference.  The verb *to be* expresses a state.  The verb *to get* expresses an action.

> The window was closed yesterday.
>   The window got closed yesterday.

With *to get*, the action is explicitly placed in the recent past.  This suggests that the window was open the day before yesterday.  With *to be*, the state is placed in the recent past, but there is no mention of the time of the action.  We are free to assume that the window has been closed since some time in the distant past.  For all we know, before yesterday the window might never have been open.

However, *to be* also leaves us free to assume that the times of state and action coincide.  Under that interpretation, *was closed* and *got closed* are rough synonyms.